# Installation of ubuntu 17.10 freezes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, asus, freeze

I have Asus laptop with windows 10 installed, but I wanted to install ubuntu 17.10 also. I’ve shrinked my partition, turned off fast boot and so on. I made a bootable usb pen-drive using rufus, selected it in UEFI as boot priority, but when i want to „try ubuntu” or „install” it is getting freezed at random moment during loading. I’ve tried everything but still no results. I checked pen-drive by installing ubuntu on my pc and everything was fine. Any ideas?

EDIT

Everything working fine with Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Can you try another pen-drive with the same method you applied first in rufus(Assuming you set GPT for UEFI)?
also try to put the pen-drive in another port of your laptop.

Another way is you can use rufus to burn the iso image to your pen-drive in DD Image Mode but before this make sure you set GPT for UEFI Scheme in rufus selection first then start it.

Reboot to your pen-drive and hope it works now.

Comment: I tried several pen-drives but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the hash of the ISO before creating the bootable drive? Sometimes ISO's don't properly mount because of file corruption, to ensure the ISO integrity always at least md5sum the ISO file. Follow the link [To check how to md5sum and to see Ubuntu hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Comment: Pen drive with this ISO worked correctly on other PC